# How do I avoid exception in the second iteration?

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging

I'm trying to display the number of times a letter appears within a string and outputting it in a new string (`compressedString`).

For example:  `aabcccccaaa` should display `a2b1c5a3`.

So far, I got `a2` to display only because I've included the `break` statement.  If I took that out, then I would get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

My question is:  How would I continue going through the whole string to obtain the rest of the aforementioned output without getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

I ran it through debugger but it still isn't clear to me.

```
public class Problem {

public static void main(String []args) {
    String str = "aabcccccaaa";
    System.out.println(compressBad(str));
}

public static String compressBad(String str) {
    int countConsecutive = 0;
    String compressedString = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        countConsecutive++;
        if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1)) {
            compressedString += "" + str.charAt(i) + countConsecutive;
            break;
        }
    }
    return compressedString;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to remove the `break` for starters.  I think you also, in the `if`, need to reset `countConsecutive` to 0, because you're starting over again counting letters.  You may need to step through your code with a debugger to find other errors, or use 'hand execution' (Google it).

Answer (score 0):

modify your for loop to terminate when `i < str.length() - 1`--this is because you are comparing the character at `i` to the character at `i + 1`, which makes your loop go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be like this:

```
if(i+1 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1))
```

because when you are is at last index of your string then also you are comparing i'th index with i+1 th index.

But after correcting this, still, this code will not give you the expected output.

Comment: I tried that and removed the break statement and my output became `a2b3c8` Why do we need the `i+1 < str.length()`?

Comment: Well, obviously because once you get to the end of the string, `str.charAt(i+1)` will index beyond the end of the string and throw an error.  However, I'm concerned Mukit's if statement won't properly handing the last sequence in your string.  Give it a go in a debugger and check it for yourself.

Comment: I have added your query in the answer. @greyskies

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would change the code.

```
public static String compressBad(String str) {
    String compressedString = "";
    if (str != null && str.length() > 0) {
        int countConsecutive = 1;
        char prevChar = str.charAt(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) != prevChar) {
                // End of a run.  Update compressedString and reset counters
                compressedString += String.valueOf(prevChar) + countConsecutive;
                prevChar = str.charAt(i);
                countConsecutive = 1;
                continue;
            }
            countConsecutive++;
        }
        compressedString += String.valueOf(prevChar) + countConsecutive;
    }
    return compressedString;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have good solutions, but I thought I would just add what I came up with:

```
public class Problem {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        String str = "aabcccccaaa";
        System.out.println(compressBad(str));
    }

    public static String compressBad(String str) {
        if (str.length() == 1) return str + "1"; // Handles single character strings
        int countConsecutive = 0;
        String compressedString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                countConsecutive++;
                if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i-1)) {
                    compressedString += "" + str.charAt(i-1) + countConsecutive;
                    countConsecutive = 0;
                }
                if (i == str.length()-1) {
                    countConsecutive++; // Needs to be incremented for the last character
                    compressedString += "" + str.charAt(i) + countConsecutive;
                }
            }
        }
        return compressedString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Problem {

   public static void main(String []args) {
     String str = "aaabc";
     System.out.println(compressBad(str));
 }

 public static String compressBad(String str) {
    int countConsecutive = 0;
    String compressedString = "";

 for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   countConsecutive++;
   //avoid index out of bounds error
   if(str.length() == (i + 1)){
       compressedString += ""+ str.charAt(i) + countConsecutive;
       countConsecutive = 0;
       break;
   }
   else if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1)){
       compressedString += ""+ str.charAt(i) + countConsecutive;
       countConsecutive = 0;
   }


}
return compressedString;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mukit09 has already mentioned the reason for your StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I offer you a more efficient implementation, using String Builder for concatenating strings:

```
private static String comppressedString(String str) {       
    if(str == null || str.equals("")) {
        return str;
    }
    if(str.length() == 1) {
        return str + "1";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(str.charAt(0)); // Add first letter
    int j = 1; // Counter for current sequence length.

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(i + 1)) { // end of characters sequence.
            sb.append(j); // Add length of previous sequence.
            if(j > 1) {
                j = 1; // Minimum sequence length is 1
            }
            sb.append(str.charAt(i+1)); // Add character of next sequence.
        } else {
            j++; // increase counter, in order to get the length of the current sequence.
        }
    }
    sb.append(j); // Add length of last sequence.

    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(comppressedString("")); // empty string
    System.out.println(comppressedString("a")); // a1
    System.out.println(comppressedString("ab")); // a1b1
    System.out.println(comppressedString("abba")); // a1b2a1
    System.out.println(comppressedString("aabcccccaaa")); // a2b1c5a3
}
```